# Selecting a single row for customers with multiple account types

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with holds multiple account types for customers. There are various account types and data for those accounts,  database is MS SQL Server

For example:

```
Account_id Account_Name,  Activated_Date, Account_Type,Account_Balance,Pending_Withdrawals.... etc

    1        Samuuel Lemin   03/01/2009      Savings                 

    2        Samuel  Lemin   01/12/2013      Way2Save       2,000,           231,

    3        Samuel  Lemin   01/12/2013      Checking                  

    4        David   Kay     11/08/2005      Savings                     

    5        David   Kay     11/08/2004      Way2Save       1200              0.0
    6        David   Kay     09/05/2003      Checking       8000              1000
   ...
```

I want to create a report with an SQL Select Query which selects all the columns of the checking account which is considered the primary account if the values of  Account_Balance, Pending_Withdrwals are not null, but if the customer has no checking account i.e.  the column values Account_Balance, Pending_Withdrwals, etc. are null for the Checking Account_Type (i.e. the primary) then

select any other account which has account information, i.e. not all these columns are null. The goal is to concatenate the account details in a case statement using spaces. If not account can be found where all the columns are not null, the return '' in the select query

The algorithm for the " SELECT query " should be:

```
    if a type=='Checking'
     then concat(Account_Name, Account_Name,Activated_Date... etc.)  
   else if here is an account with account details
    concat(Account_Name,...
```

Null columns should be concatenated as '' in the select query.

The SQL select query should look something like the following:

```
  select case CustomerAccount=
  when exists(
    select Account_Balance,Pending_Withdrawals from Accounts where accountType='Checking'
   )
   then

   concat(select top 1.Account_Id from Account where Account_Type='Checking',

          select top  1.Account_Name from Account where Account_Type='Checking',

         other columns...

   when exists(

      select Account_Balance,Pending_Withdrawals from Accounts where accountType='Savings'
   )

   then

     concat(....)

   when exists(

    select Account_Balance,Pending_Withdrawals from Accounts where accountType='Way2Save'
    )

   then concat(...)
```

How do I write the select case query that returns a single row of the concatenated columns as a String for which the  Account_Type where not all the column values are null or '' if all the Account_Types columns are all null?

For example given the table above I want to return from the select query for Samuel Lemin the concatenated String as

'2        Samuel  Lemin   01/12/2013      Way2Save         2,000,           231'

because for Samuel Lemin,  Account_Balance,Pending_Withdrwals are null for Checking

For  David Kay.

'David   Kay     09/05/2003      Checking       8000              1000'

because the Checking account type has Account_Balance and Pending_Withdrawal values and it is the primary account we want to show first

Comment: show us the expected output.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: If the Account_Type is 'Checking' and there is data in some of the columns I want to return the concatenated columns for that row for all the customers in a  Select Query, otherwise if for the Account_Type='Checking' all columns have null values, then the Select should return a concatenated row of the columns of the next  Account_Type that does not have all its columns as null.

Comment: The expected output is now shown, sorry my bad